# Filling array with values in ImageJ macro

Tags: arrays, macros, imagej

I have a 2D array that I would like to fill with numbers, one row at a time. For example, if my array was n x m in size, I would write loop m times to fill each row with n values. How do I do I write this for an ImageJ macro? I would normally write something like:

```
n=10;
m=5;
array=newArray(n,m);
FOR (i=0;i<m;i+=1){
numbers=newArray(m);
array[*,i]=numbers;
}
```

However, `array[*,i]` obviously does not work, nor does `array[j][i]` if I add another loop 'j' within loop 'i'. Could someone please help? I am very new to writing macros in ImageJ. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wayne Rasband(developer of ImageJ)](http://imagej.1557.n6.nabble.com/Two-Dimensional-Arrays-td3704799.html%3E) the macro language does not support two dimensional arrays.

I would suggest you consider writing a plugin in Java. There is a good guide [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFwQFjAH&url=http://www.gm.fh-koeln.de/~konen/WPF-BV/tutorial-ImageJ_V1.71.pdf&ei=NK5RUJvrA-mw0QWiu4CgAg&usg=AFQjCNFHS15Tn323YiG6srGOm7-raALGtw&cad=rja) here that also compares macros and plugins. The more complicated the image processing the more you should think about using Java.

Other options include using Fiji's python interface.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was intending to do something quite simple, but I guess if I cannot create a macro for it, I'll have to write a Java plugin... I also just realised newArray(n,m) actually creates a 2-element array, not 2D array! Should have known!